Different output on GCC and on Visual Studio
I tried to write a program in CPP which gets an infix expression, turns it into a postfix expression and then calculates the expression, using a stack-class executed by me.
I thought what I wrote works because I ran several tests on it on Visual Studio. But I don't know why, the tests have result X on Visual Studio and result Y on GCC. For an example, when I run the program and enter (5+3)*((20/10)+(8-6)) on Visual Studio, it prints 32. On GCC, on the other hand, it prints 0.
So, my question is whether someone knows what might cause this difference? Maybe something different in the compilers?
I think that it might be caused by Undefined Behaviour. But even if it does, I have no about idea about where it is invoked...
(Btw, in GCC Instead of separating the Stack.h to a different file, I just wrote it above main - the output is still different on Visual Studio)
main.cpp :
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool operatorsPrecedenceCheck(string& str, Stack<char>& stk, const char& ch)
{
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
    {
        Stack<char> help(stk.getSize());
        char stkTop = '\0';
        if (!stk.isEmpty())
            stkTop = stk.top();
        while (!stk.isEmpty() && stkTop != '(')
        {
            stkTop = stk.top();
            if (stk.top() == '*' || stk.top() == '/')
            {
                str += stk.pop();
                str += ' ';
            }
            else
                help.push(stk.pop());
        }
        while (!help.isEmpty())
            stk.push(help.pop());

        stk.push(ch);

        return 1;
    }
    else if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
    {
        stk.push(ch);

        return 1;
    }


    return 0;

}
bool parenthesisCheck(string& str, Stack<char>& stk, const char& ch)
{
    if (ch == '(')
    {
        stk.push(ch);

        return 1;
    }
    else if (ch == ')')
    {
        while (stk.top() != '(')
        {
            str += stk.pop();
            str += ' ';
        }
        stk.pop();

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}

string infixToPostfix(const string& exp)
{
    string str = "";
    Stack<char> stk(exp.length());
    bool actionExecuted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); ++i)
    {
        actionExecuted = parenthesisCheck(str, stk, exp[i]);
        if (!actionExecuted)
            actionExecuted = operatorsPrecedenceCheck(str, stk, exp[i]);
        if (!actionExecuted)
        {
            if (exp[i] >= '0' && exp[i] <= '9')
            {
                for (; exp[i] >= '0' && exp[i] <= '9'; ++i)
                    str += exp[i];

                str += ' ';
                --i;
            }
            else
                throw"An illegal value in the expression\n";
        }
    }
    while (!stk.isEmpty())
    {
        str += stk.pop();
        str += ' ';
    }

    str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 1); //Cause of space

    return str;

}

int getValueFromString(const string& str, int& i)
{
    int result = 0;
    int amountOfDigits = 0;
    while (str[i + amountOfDigits] >= '0' && str[i + amountOfDigits] <= '9')
        ++amountOfDigits;

    for (int j = pow(10, amountOfDigits - 1); j >= 1; j /= 10)
        result += (str[i++] - '0') * j;
    --i;

    return result;
}

float calcPostfix(const string& str)
{
    Stack<int>stk(str.length() / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            stk.push(getValueFromString(str, i));
        else if (str[i] == '/')
            stk.push((float)1 / stk.pop() * stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '*')
            stk.push(stk.pop() * stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '+')
            stk.push(stk.pop() + stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '-')
            stk.push(-1 * (stk.pop() - stk.pop()));
        else
            throw"Unknown Operator in Calculating Postfix\\n";
    }

    return stk.top();

}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        string exp;
        cout << "enter an infix expression as a string" << endl;
        cin >> exp;
        string postfix = infixToPostfix(exp);
        cout << postfix << endl;
        cout << calcPostfix(postfix) << endl;
    }
    catch (const char* exc)
    {
        cout << exc;
        exit(-1);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Unknown Error has occured\\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;

}

Stack.h :
#ifndef MYSTACK_H
#define MYSTACK_H

template <class T>
class Stack
{
    //Inner class help
    void swap(Stack<T> &a, Stack<T>& b);

    T* data;
    int capacity;
    int size;
public:
    //Constructors & Destructor
    Stack();
    Stack(int capacity_);
    Stack(const Stack<T>& toCopy);
    Stack(Stack<T>&& toMove);
    ~Stack();

    //Methods
    int getCapacity() const;
    int getSize() const;
    void clear();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    T pop();
    void push(const T& toInsert);
    T top() const;

    //Operators
    Stack<T>& operator= (const Stack<T>& toAssign);
    Stack<T>& operator=(Stack<T>&& toMove);
};

//Inner class help
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T>& a, Stack<T>& b)
{
    T* temp_1 = a.data;
    a.data = b.data;
    b.data = temp_1;

    int temp_2 = a.size;
    a.size = b.size;
    b.size = temp_2;

    temp_2 = a.capacity;
    a.capacity = b.capacity;
    b.capacity = temp_2;
}

//Constructors & Destructor
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() : data(nullptr), capacity(0), size(0) {}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int capacity_) : capacity(capacity_), size(0) 
{
    data = new T[capacity];
    if (!data)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& toCopy)
{
    size = 0;
    capacity = toCopy.capacity;
    data = new T[capacity];
    if (!data)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < toCopy.size; ++i, ++size)
        data[i] = toCopy.data[i];
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T>&& toMove)
{
    data = nullptr;
    size = capacity = 0;

    swap(*this, toMove);
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    clear();
}

//Methods
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::getCapacity() const
{
    return capacity;
}
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
{
    if (data)
    {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
    size = capacity = 0;
}
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return size == 0;
}
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isFull() const
{
    return size == capacity;
}
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw"Couldn't pop - Stack is empty\n";

    T toReturn = data[--size];
    T* temp = new T[capacity];
    if (!temp)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    delete[]data;
    data = temp;
    
    return toReturn;
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& toInsert)
{
    if (isFull())
        throw "Couldn't push - stack is full\n";

    T* temp = new T[capacity];
    if (!temp)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    temp[size++] = toInsert;
    delete[]data;
    data = temp;
}
template<class T>
T Stack<T>::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw"Couln't return top - Stack is empty\n";

    return data[size - 1];
}

//Operators
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T>& toAssign)
{
    if (data)
        delete[]data;

    Stack<T>help = toAssign;
    swap(*this,help);
    return *this;
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T>&& toMove)
{
    if (data)
        delete[]data;

    data = nullptr;
    size = capacity = 0;
    
    swap(*this, toMove);
    return *this;
}

#endif

Code on GCC
template <class T>
class Stack
{
    //Inner class help
    void swap(Stack<T> &a, Stack<T>& b);

    T* data;
    int capacity;
    int size;
public:
    //Constructors & Destructor
    Stack();
    Stack(int capacity_);
    Stack(const Stack<T>& toCopy);
    Stack(Stack<T>&& toMove);
    ~Stack();

    //Methods
    int getCapacity() const;
    int getSize() const;
    void clear();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    T pop();
    void push(const T& toInsert);
    T top() const;

    //Operators
    Stack<T>& operator= (const Stack<T>& toAssign);
    Stack<T>& operator=(Stack<T>&& toMove);
};

//Inner class help
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T>& a, Stack<T>& b)
{
    T* temp_1 = a.data;
    a.data = b.data;
    b.data = temp_1;

    int temp_2 = a.size;
    a.size = b.size;
    b.size = temp_2;

    temp_2 = a.capacity;
    a.capacity = b.capacity;
    b.capacity = temp_2;
}

//Constructors & Destructor
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() : data(nullptr), capacity(0), size(0) {}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int capacity_) : capacity(capacity_), size(0) 
{
    data = new T[capacity];
    if (!data)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& toCopy)
{
    size = 0;
    capacity = toCopy.capacity;
    data = new T[capacity];
    if (!data)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < toCopy.size; ++i, ++size)
        data[i] = toCopy.data[i];
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T>&& toMove)
{
    data = nullptr;
    size = capacity = 0;

    swap(*this, toMove);
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    clear();
}

//Methods
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::getCapacity() const
{
    return capacity;
}
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
{
    if (data)
    {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
    size = capacity = 0;
}
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return size == 0;
}
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isFull() const
{
    return size == capacity;
}
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw"Couldn't pop - Stack is empty\n";

    T toReturn = data[--size];
    T* temp = new T[size];
    if (!temp)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    delete[]data;
    data = temp;
    
    return toReturn;
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& toInsert)
{
    if (isFull())
        throw "Couldn't push - stack is full\n";

    T* temp = new T[size + 1];
    if (!temp)
        throw "ERROR - couldn't allocate memory\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    temp[size++] = toInsert;
    delete[]data;
    data = temp;
}
template<class T>
T Stack<T>::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw"Couln't return top - Stack is empty\n";

    return data[size - 1];
}

//Operators
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T>& toAssign)
{
    if (data)
        delete[]data;

    Stack<T>help = toAssign;
    swap(*this,help);
    return *this;
}
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T>&& toMove)
{
    if (data)
        delete[]data;

    data = nullptr;
    size = capacity = 0;
    
    swap(*this, toMove);
    return *this;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool operatorsPrecedenceCheck(string& str, Stack<char>& stk, const char& ch)
{
if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
    {
        Stack<char> help(stk.getSize());
        char stkTop = '\0';
        if (!stk.isEmpty())
            stkTop = stk.top();
        while (!stk.isEmpty() && stkTop!='(') //Not mentioned but required
        {
            stkTop = stk.top();
            if (stk.top() == '*' || stk.top() == '/')
            {
                str += stk.pop();
                str += ' ';
            }
            else
                help.push(stk.pop());
        }
        while (!help.isEmpty())
            stk.push(help.pop());

        stk.push(ch);
        
        return 1;
    }
    else if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
    {
        stk.push(ch);

        return 1;
    }
    

    return 0;
}
bool parenthesisCheck(string& str, Stack<char>& stk, const char& ch)
{
    if (ch == '(')
    {
        stk.push(ch);

        return 1;
    }
    else if (ch == ')')
    {
        while (stk.top() != '(')
        {
            str += stk.pop();
            str += ' ';
        }
        stk.pop();

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

string infixToPostfix(const string &exp)
{
    string str = "";
    Stack<char> stk(exp.length());
    bool actionExecuted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); ++i)
    {
        actionExecuted = parenthesisCheck(str, stk, exp[i]);
        if (!actionExecuted)
            actionExecuted = operatorsPrecedenceCheck(str, stk, exp[i]);
        if (!actionExecuted)
        {
            if (exp[i] >= '0' && exp[i] <= '9')
            {
                for (; exp[i] >= '0' && exp[i] <= '9'; ++i)
                    str += exp[i];

                str += ' ';
                --i;
            }
            else
                throw"An illegal value in the expression\n";
        }
    }
    while (!stk.isEmpty())
    {
        str += stk.pop();
        str += ' ';
    }

    str = str.substr(0,str.length() - 1); //Cause of space

    return str;
}

int getValueFromString(const string& str, int &i)
{
    int result = 0;
    int amountOfDigits = 0;
    while (str[i+amountOfDigits] >= '0' && str[i+amountOfDigits] <= '9')
        ++amountOfDigits;

        for (int j = pow(10,amountOfDigits-1); j>=1; j /= 10)
            result += (str[i++] - '0') * j;
        --i;

    return result;
}

float calcPostfix(const string& str)
{
    Stack<int>stk(str.length()/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            stk.push(getValueFromString(str, i));
        else if (str[i] == '/')
            stk.push((float)1 / stk.pop() * stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '*')
            stk.push(stk.pop() * stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '+')
            stk.push(stk.pop() + stk.pop());
        else if (str[i] == '-')
            stk.push(-1 * (stk.pop() - stk.pop()));
        else
            throw"Unknown Operator in Calculating Postfix\n";
    }

    return stk.top();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        string exp;
        cout << "enter an infix expression as a string" << endl;
        cin >> exp;
        string postfix = infixToPostfix(exp);
        cout << postfix << endl;
        cout << calcPostfix(postfix) << endl;
    }
    catch (const char* exc)
    {
        cout << exc;
        exit(-1);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Unknown Error has occured\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}


I suggest fixing up your code and providing a proper [mre].

I tried to write a program in CPP which gets an infix expression, turns it into a postfix expression and then calculates the expression. -- If that's your goal, why not use std::stack instead of writing your own?  The infix -> postfix expression logic still has to be written, but without having to micromanage stack classes.

@CSStudent -- If the code works "differently", the code is not working at all.

@PaulMcKenzie Because it's a common data structures assignment? Students are required to write the stack, and are given a task that utilizes it. If your intent is to call into question the logic of the professor, asking OP is the wrong tack.

@CSStudent -- Use std::stack anyway for the first time coding this.  Why?  Because in all likelihood, you are doing something with your Stack class that could have been detected more easily if you initially used std::stack.  If you're using Visual C++, the debug runtime will catch these types of errors.  Once you get the code working with std::stack, then reintroduce the home-made stack class.

@CSStudent -- If simple code like this produces two different results from two differing compilers, then 99.9% of the time, the code is faulty.

Undefined Behavior is usually the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a

@CSStudent -- I suggest you stick with g++ and get it working there since you know you can reproduce the broken results there.  Once you get it working there with the changes you will make, make those same changes for Visual C++.  Also, I don't know if your teacher wrote the Stack class, but one suggestion is to not have pop return any value.  This would make the Stack class somewhat more like std::stack.  In other words, if you want the top value in the stack, you must call top() to get it.

An easier way to write a stack is to wrap another structure like a vector or linked list. At least when I taught, the stack and queue were dirt-simple homeworks. The linked list from a prior assignment was thoroughly unit tested, and the stack merely wrapped it. Then there's no need for all of this isFull() stuff. The advice to use std::stack will allow you to thoroughly test your infix->postfix code. Once that's solid, you can then bring back your custom stack and troubleshoot it. It's always about breaking it down into manageable pieces.

@CSStudent -- For efficiency, what if all I want to do is keep popping and not care about the return value?  Your code is inefficient in that pop will always return a copy of the value, and copying can be expensive if the type stored in Stack has an expensive copy operation.   C++ is designed for efficiency, and if I want the top value, then I will explicitly ask for it by calling top.   Another difference between your class and std::stack is that top()  returns a reference for std::stack::top, not a copy of the value.

And I didn't use linked lists nor vector because it's for the next assignment.

Retired Ninja -- I updated the code about 1 minute after I posted it with this problem, It's really odd indeed. ty!

@PaulMcKenzie -- We're supposed to learn how to use the std::stack after this assignment, so what we learnt is the use of a stack and opaquely how it is implemented. But thanks for the suggestions. I guess I should write my own stack more similarly to the std::stack. I'll look at its details later.

@sweenish -- Thanks, you were right, the problem is in my stack. I'll look at it later again tomorrow. Thank you all!

@CSStudent -- The issue seems to be the subtraction.   Rewrite the subtraction to do as stated -- store the top value into a temporary, then pop, then store the top in another temporary and pop.  Then do the subtraction using the temporaries instead of having two pop calls on one line.

This may be relevant.  I believe the issue is that you are altering the stack multiple times on one logical line of code, and the order is not specified as to which pop is going to be done first.   A by-product of writing the pop to not return a value is that you would have been forced to make two (or more) explicit calls to top and then pop, making the order well-defined in the subtraction.  So yes, your stack class is faulty, but in a way you didn't realize.

After going through this yourself and testing, you should write up an answer if after changing the Stack class actually produces the correct results (it should).

else if (str[i] == '-') stk.push(-1 * (stk.pop() - stk.pop())); -- To be more exact, it's this code that seems to be at fault.

@PaulMcKenzie -- Thank you so much! I didn't know about "Order of Evaluations" before, and this is very helpful, and it all makes sense now. I'll work on the stack now, but I just wanna ask if I'm not mistaken when saying that the else if (str[i] == '/')  stk.push((float)1 / stk.pop() * stk.pop()); line is faulty too

yes, the same problem is present in that line (see my answer), it happens to work in msvc, gcc and clang but there's no guarantee that it'll be the same in other compilers or even future versions of those compilers

@JesperJuhl -- Thanks, I'll read what's relevant

@PaulMcKenzie -- May I ask why does top() returns a reference?

@CSStudent -- A reference is returned for efficiency, plus allows the user to modify the top value directly.  If the user of std::stack actually wants a copy, then they can explicitly do it for a std::stack<T> theStack; by using T val = theStack.top();, otherwise T& val = theStack.top(); will give a reference.

Thank you very much @PaulMcKenzie, you helped me a lot!
Btw, I just got 100 on the assignment. Thanks!

In stk.pop() - stk.pop() there is no guarantee that the left hand pop() happens first, if you change to:
auto a = stk.pop();
auto b = stk.pop();
stk.push(-1 * (a - b));

You'll get the same behaviour across different compilers.
You have the same problem in (float)1 / stk.pop() * stk.pop().
Your original code with some added debugging: https://godbolt.org/z/xEKzeTzvn
The fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/oczef5hrj

Thank you! But I got a few questions: Firstly, why did you use auto in the function calcPostfix? calcPostfix calculates an expression, which has integers. Secondly, is the purpose of the additional debugging to let you see what are the stack's size and top() in every line? And if it is, then why would you print the stack's size and top() and not something else? Thirdly, why did you change the \n in lines 337 (throw"Unknown Operator in Calculating Postfix\\n";) and 362 (cout << "Unknown Error has occured\\n";)?

Why not use auto? it saves me from having to look up what the data types are. Not sure what you're asking about with your second question, I just printed some values so you can see where the behaviour diverges between the compilers. I didn't change the line, I simply copied your original code from the question.

Alright, I'll try to ask it more clearly: Why would you print the info you printed, specifically where you printed it. and not somewhere else in the code? And why would you print this info, and not another info?

@CSStudent because this is the information being used at this point in the program and shows where it was going wrong

Yes, but did you choose to print the info there for finding the error? Or for showing it to me?

to find the error, by comparing the output I could see where the program diverged between clang and gcc. Of course using a debugger would be better than printing values

You could say where the program diverged between clang and gcc by printing there values, but you couldn't know that printing the values there would result in the diversion-point reveal. Hence, how did you print values exactly where the problem occures? Was it pure luck.?

@CSStudent -- It is not pure luck.  The bottom line is that you know you are pushing something into the stack at some point.  You take those critical points where you are doing this and log what is going on.  This is a skill you will need to have as a programmer.   It isn't simply "I know the bug is here, so let me log things", no, that is not the way to approach this.  You log all the points where your program may go wrong.  The method that AlanBirtles used is what I used to see that the subtraction was faulty, and that is to log what was being put into the stack.

The postfix string was the same for both compilers so the problem had to be in calcPostfix, i then just instrumented the whole function

Alright thanks. Btw, I just finished it and got 100. Gigantic thanks!

Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I asked what I asked to better-know how to achieve this skill.

Btw, one last thing: In the following code I get warning C6011
const char *stkTop = nullptr; if (!stk.isEmpty()) stkTop = &stk.top(); while (!stk.isEmpty() && *stkTop!='(') {}
Do I get the warning because it doesn't know if &stk.top() equals to nullptr?

The warning is probably given because you are conditionally setting stkTop in the if statement, thus it is possible that stkTop is still nullptr when the while loop executes.

@PaulMcKenzie -- Yes, but it assigns stkTop=&stk.top(); if (!stk.isEmpty). And in the while loop, it will only do *stkTop!='(' if !stk.isEmpty). Hence it will dereference stkTop only if !stk.isEmpty, and if ``!stk.isEmpty`, it means that stkTop has already been assigned by &stk.top() .

The compiler only knows what happens at compile time.  It is not looking at what will occur at runtime.  It's the same thing with this: int foo(int x) { if (x > 0 && x <= 100) return 1; else if (x >100) return 2; } and seeing a warning that all paths are not returning a value, even though at runtime, you are calling foo(1);.

The compiler might be able to work out that stk.isEmpty() doesn't change between the two calls to it and therefore stkTop will always be assigned but that's probably a deeper analysis than most compilers do, the simplest way to silence the warning is to move the while loop into the body of the if statement, it might even make your code marginally more efficient

@AlanBirtles -- Thanks, I now understood the concept.  Thanks for the tip, too.
